spark scala isolation forest on groupby column
I have a dataset like :

I want to group the data by Col1, Col2, Col3 and would like to apply isolation forest on that group by result.
I am able to apply isolation forest if col3 value is just single value.
I would like to apply Isolation Forest to the group based on groupBy values.
I am using Scala Spark for this.
Could you please help me with this.
Thanks,
PML
I am able to apply isolation forest if col3 value is just single value.
I would like to apply Isolation Forest to the group based on groupBy values.
:require isolation-forest_3.5.0_2.13-3.0.5.jar

import com.linkedin.relevance.isolationforest._

val data = spark.read.option("header", "true").option("inferschema","true").csv("D:\\data.csv")

val groupedData = data.groupBy("col1","col2","col3").agg(collect_list("Values").as("Values"))

def processList(arr: Seq[Double]): Seq[Double] = {
    val rows = arr.map(d => Row(d))
    val schema = StructType(Seq(StructField("vector", DoubleType, nullable = false)))
    val df = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(rows), schema)
    val assembler = new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(Array("vector")).setOutputCol("features")
    val featureDF = assembler.transform(df)
    val isolation_forest = new IsolationForest().setMaxSamples(53).setMaxFeatures(1).setPredictionCol("predicted_label").setFeaturesCol("features").setScoreCol("outlier_score").setContamination(0.1)
    val model = isolation_forest.fit(featureDF)
    val features_scores_df = model.transform(featureDF)
    val scoresList = features_scores_df.select("outlier_score").as[Double].collect().toSeq
    scoresList
}

val processListUDF: UserDefinedFunction = udf(processList _)

val resultDF = groupedData.withColumn("processed_values", processListUDF($"Values"))

resultDF.show()

this is my code.
it throws error if I try to show resultDF content.
error is as follows:
 org.apache.spark.SparkException: [FAILED_EXECUTE_UDF] Failed to execute user defined function (`$read$$iw$$Lambda$5154/1868469734`: (array<double>) => array<double>).
        at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.failedExecuteUserDefinedFunctionError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:198)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors.failedExecuteUserDefinedFunctionError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage3.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenEvaluatorFactory$WholeStageCodegenPartitionEvaluator$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenEvaluatorFactory.scala:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$getByteArrayRdd$1(SparkPlan.scala:388)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:893)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:893)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:367)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:331)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:166)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at $line78.$read$$iw.processList(<console>:4)
        at $line96.$read$$iw.$anonfun$processListUDF$1(<console>:1)
        ... 20 more


What is isolation forest? Do you have an issue with the code (if so, show us what you've got so far)? Or is it with the algorithm?

Isolation forest is used for anomaly detection.

How are you computing the isolation forest? It seems you have a routine to do so if you have "all the same group".

Assuming scala here and that this is a spark Dataset, you'd simply groupBy:
table.groupBy("COL1", "COL2", "COL3")

You then need to aggregate which presumably cannot be done through SQL operations.
One possible route is to cast from RelationalGroupedDataset (returned from groupBy) to KeyValueGroupedDataset:
table.groupBy("COL1", "COL2", "COL3").as[(String, String, String), (String, String, String, Double)]

Now you can use mapGroups to implement your operation on the group of values per (String, String, String) group:
table.groupBy("COL1", "COL2", "COL3").as[(String, String, String), (String, String, String, Double)]
  .mapGroups { (
      (c1, c2, c3): (String, String, String),
      rowIter: Iterator[(String, String, String, Double)]
    ) =>
    // compute what you need
    // return tuple that represents the columns you want returned
    (c1, c2, c3, computedValue)
  }

Obviously could simplify the tuples with case classes for the table schema/s.
FWIW: if the number of values returned per group is extremely large, this is going to present a computational problem.
